# Knockout JS : Template binding Issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

When I'm using Knockout Template binding, I get the following error in IE8

> Unhandled exception at line 58, column 28 in
>   http://www.example.com/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js
>   0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="template :  { name: 'person-template', foreach: people }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>
```

**Script**

```
var UserTabViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;    
    self.people = [{ name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 }, 
                   { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 }];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var userTabViewModel = new UserTabViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(userTabViewModel);
});
```

It's not tested in any other browser since I only have IE8 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
var UserTabViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;    
    self.people = [{ name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 }, 
                   { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 }];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var userTabViewModel = new UserTabViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(userTabViewModel);
});
```

works fine with knockout 2.2.1

http://jsfiddle.net/rsma7/1/

but fails with knockout 2.1.0

http://jsfiddle.net/rsma7/2/

Try updating your knockout to 2.2.1. It seems to [only corrects](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/083b753b2161ebb8703ca45a487774ce34509aa7) this bug actually! (the error is on the `clean`)

Comment: thnks dude, let me try this.. :)

Comment: its Worked, tried with knockout-3.1.0.... Thanks... Its because of the version Issue.